# terrain grid rendering problem

Tags: c++, directx9, grid

I'm using DirectX 9 and attempting to write a simple terrain generation object.

I'm running into trouble with the rendering - I'm hoping that this is a common problem, and someone could spot the problem by the output:

[image]

I've generated vertices, indices and I'm attempting to render a triangle strip (as it's supposed to be the most efficent way to do a grid.

It looks like I've made some kind of error in vertex or index generation, although I can't see what.  I've posted my terrain class [here](http://pastebin.com/3WSTNWCv).  Can someone have a look and suggest what I've done wrong?

Comment: Added the image for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with the triangle strip - it's going to be much harder to reason about than a triangle list and the graphics driver can perform the conversion automatically anyway. It looks to me like your indices are off, at least- every triangle is drawn connected to vertex 0.

What you should mainly consider is that you don't actually have X many triangles- you have the same triangle repeated X times. Generate one triangle or two triangles, then transform it using the D3DX mathematical library into the positions that you want. Here's some example code.

```
void GenTriGrid(int numVertRows, int numVertCols,
    float dx, float dz,
    const D3DXVECTOR3& center,
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3>& verts,
    std::vector<DWORD>& indices)
{
    int numVertices = numVertRows*numVertCols;
    int numCellRows = numVertRows-1;
    int numCellCols = numVertCols-1;

    int numTris = numCellRows*numCellCols*2;

    float width = (float)numCellCols * dx;
    float depth = (float)numCellRows * dz;

    //===========================================
    // Build vertices.

    // We first build the grid geometry centered about the origin
    // and on the xz-plane, row by row and in a top-down fashion.
    // We then translate the grid vertices so that they are
    // centered about the specified parameter 'center'.

    verts.resize( numVertices );

    // Offsets to translate grid from quadrant 4 to center of
    // coordinate system.
    float xOffset = -width * 0.5f;
    float zOffset =  depth * 0.5f;

    int k = 0;
    for(float i = 0; i < numVertRows; ++i) {

        for(float j = 0; j < numVertCols; ++j)
        {
            // Negate the depth coordinate to put in
            // quadrant four.  Then offset to center about
            // coordinate system.
            verts[k].x =  j * dx + xOffset;
            verts[k].z = -i * dz + zOffset;
            verts[k].y =  0.0f;
            // Translate so that the center of the grid is at the
            // specified 'center' parameter.
            D3DXMATRIX T;
            D3DXMatrixTranslation(&T,
                center.x,
                center.y,
                center.z);
            D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&verts[k], &verts[k], &T);
            ++k; // Next vertex
        }
    }
    indices.resize(numTris * 3);

    // Generate indices for each quad.
    int k = 0;
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < (DWORD)numCellRows; ++i)
    {
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < (DWORD)numCellCols; ++j)
        {
            indices[k]     =   i   * numVertCols + j;
            indices[k + 1] =   i   * numVertCols + j + 1;
            indices[k + 2] = (i+l) * numVertCols + j;

            indices[k + 3] = (i+l) * numVertCols + j;
            indices[k + 4] =   i   * numVertCols + j + 1;
            indices[k + 5] = (i+l) * numVertCols + j + 1;

            // next quad
            k += 6;
        }
    }
}
```

On an only somewhat tangental note, I haven't understood your code- it's totally illegible. It's a fairly incredible feat that *you* can read it.

No way can I decode 400 lines of redundant error checking (never heard of resource-managing classes?), HRESULTs, references to non-posted classes, variables declared about six million billion miles away from where they're used, global variables and *fixed function pipeline*, horrific Hungarian notation, some really crazy indentation, etc.

I'd suggest that you learn some more about coding. Here's an unfortunate lesson- the Windows API, DirectX, etc are all C APIs, designed 20 years ago (or more!) for inter-process communication and do not reflect at all good practice for in-application use.As such, it's actually really a bad idea to learn from their example. You should not return error codes- you should throw exceptions, and if you must return an error code, grab an enumeration for it- do not use a weak error code like HRESULT. Hungarian Notation is quite worthless in modern C++- the compiler will tell you the type and scope of any variable, at any time. CString is so bad, it's implementation is mandated to be illegal for the C++ Standard string class- which should always be preferred. You should not use new/delete directly, but rather favour the use of `std::vector` for dynamically allocated arrays- it's vastly safer and no less performant. These `Initialize` functions? That's what a constructor is for, buddy.

Also, fixed-function pipeline (that is, FVF and stuff) is deader than a dodo- even phones have shaders these days.

Comment: DirectX isn't a C API though :)

Comment: @heishe: It's COM, which is the same thing, effectively.

Comment: Hungarian notation can be useful in those *few* cases, but usually you find those cases are bad design, and so its a good indicator to refactor.

Comment: Sorry for coming from a COM background.  The indentation looks fine in my IDE, I just dumped it into pastebin, if it was so offensive to read, skip onto the next question. It's only a prototype, I didn't expect that the response would be centred around moaning about coding style.  The code supplied in DeadMGs response was straight out of Frank D Luna.  Yeah, I've seen that algorithm, my purpose for this was to _learn_ about mesh generation, although that was missed by DeadMG.  Grow up MG ;)

Comment: @jtsPimp: Never said it was mine, I only said it was an example.